# Problems while loading initial-data.yml in play 2.0

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, snakeyaml

I am trying to port to YABE in play1.2.4 to play 2.0.4  Java. For that I created a initial-data.yml and tried to load it with Global.java

```
#Users
users:
    - !!models.User
        email:      bob@gmail.com
        password:   secret
        fullname:   Bob
        isAdmin:    true
#Posts

posts:

    - !!models.Post
        id:         1
        title:      About the model layer
        postedAt:   2009-06-14
        author:     
            - !!models.User
                email: bob@gmail.com
        content:    >
                    The model has a central position in a Play! application. Cut....
```

My Global.java is below

```
public void onStart(Application app) {
        InitialData.insert(app);
    }

    static class InitialData {
        public static void insert(Application app) {
            if(Ebean.find(User.class).findRowCount() == 0) {
                Map<String, List<Object>> all = (Map<String, List<Object>>)Yaml.load("initial-data.yml");
                Ebean.save(all.get("users"));
                Ebean.save(all.get("posts"));
                Ebean.save(all.get("comments"));
            }
        }
    }
```

While loading I am getting following errors

**ConstructorException: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:models.Post; exception=Cannot create property=author for JavaBean=models.Post@1; No suitable constructor with 3 arguments found for class models.User**

```
org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.ConstructorException: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:models.Post; exception=Cannot create property=author for JavaBean=models.Post@1; No suitable constructor with 3 arguments found for class models.User

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:333)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:183)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructSequenceStep2(BaseConstructor.java:277)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructSequence(BaseConstructor.java:248)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlSeq.construct(SafeConstructor.java:440)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:183)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(BaseConstructor.java:326)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.constructMapping2ndStep(SafeConstructor.java:143)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructMapping(BaseConstructor.java:307)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlMap.construct(SafeConstructor.java:459)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:183)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:142)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:128)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:480)

     org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:411)
```

Any Idea why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manuel, Thanks for the help.

When I slightly modified the YAML i got it working,  I just removed the "-", which is in front of the "model.class"

```
#Users
users:
    - !!models.User
        email:      bob@gmail.com
        password:   secret
        fullname:   Bob
        isAdmin:    true
#Posts

posts:

    - !!models.Post
        id:         1
        title:      About the model layer
        postedAt:   2009-06-14
        author: !!models.User
                email: bob@gmail.com
        content:    >
                    The model has a central position in a Play! application. Cut....
```

Any idea what "-" stands for?

Comment: I think '-' say "element in list"

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while that I have worked with YAML, but it looks as though you were re-creating a new User in the Post, instead of referencing Bob.

I'd try something like this:

```
models.User(bob):
  email:      bob@gmail.com
  password:   secret
  fullname:   Bob
  isAdmin:    true

models.Post(firstPost):
  id:         1
  title:      About the model layer
  postedAt:   2009-06-14
  author:     bob
  content:    The model has a central position in a Play! application.
```